# Ratio data with categorical events

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation, dataset

I have a question about treating qualitative (categorical) events within otherwise quantitative (ratio scale) data. Without going into too much detain, the experiment is on throwing. I measure the distance between the target and the result of the throw for each attempt. Some attempts are failed because the participant hits an obstacle on the way to the target. In the end the dependent variable may look something like this:
[.2 .1 .3 .2 -1 .2 .2 .8 -1] where the values may range from 0 to anything, but -1 represent the obstacle hits. What are some ways to deal with such categorical data within quantitative variable? I cannot just throw them out because they are meaningful from the performance perspective. Substituting with some high error distance seems arbitrary. Is there anything else? In the end I'm interested in how people get better at throwing as a result of practice.

Comment: Could you please explain what meaning the $-1$ values have "from the performance perspective"?  Do you want somehow to incorporate the rate at which flawed attempts occur into your assessment of changes in throwing ability?  (If so, this is not pure censoring and needs a more careful treatment.)

Comment: Good question: I was interpreting it as the OP wanted to know, had the obstacle been absent, how far from the target would the throw have landed (pretty far if they are that bad i'd think)

Comment: -1's are arbitrary values. It's pretty much a dummy code for an obstacle hit. It could be any other number as long as it is easily distinguishable from the quantitative measure of distance between target and throw result.

Comment: The goal is to incorporate the obstacle hit information in addition to the error distance information. Ideally, in the same analysis. That's why it was appealing to substitute the obstacle hits with some relatively high value of error distance (say, 3SD above mean performance around the obstacle hit).

Answer (score 1):

In statistical terminology, the -1 data represent **censored** data. Two general approaches for sensoring are [multiple imputation](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jls/mifaq.html) and [censored likelihood](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~stat415/meeker/ml_estimation_chapter.pdf)

One of those two should be helpful.

Comment: Attempts ending at an obstacle are probably very bad even without obstacle, leading to unhandy informative censoring. Otherwise good idea.

Comment: Yes..but that is what the OP is trying to do. How much to reduce the participant's accuracy based on an obstacle hit. All I could think of was the above two as systematic approaches that avoid arbitrary "subsitiution".

Comment: Sorry, what is OP?

Comment: OP = Original Poster (i.e., you)